# Control Access from Excel: remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm running a simple script, described below.

```
Sub New_Liabilities()

MsgBox ("It may take a while for the query to complete; be patient.  Please wait for the 'Done' message to confirm that the task is complete.")

    Dim strDatabasePath As String
    Dim PathToDB As String
    Dim accApp As Access.Application
    Set accApp = New Access.Application

    PathOfDatabase = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Manual_Updates").Range("PathToAccess")
    accApp.OpenCurrentDatabase PathOfDatabase
    accApp.DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    accApp.DoCmd.RunMacro "Macro_Prep_Liabilities"
    accApp.DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    accApp.Quit
    Set accApp = Nothing

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

MsgBox "Done!  All processes complete!!"

End Sub
```

I keep getting an error message that reads: 
`'remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable'`.

The problem occurs on this line:

```
accApp.DoCmd.RunMacro "Macro_Prep_Liabilities"
```

Access needs to run several update queries and several append queries, and it takes a while for everything to complete.  Sometimes the process crashes after about 10 minutes, sometimes is crashes after about 5 minutes, but sometimes it works fine.

This whole process is running on a UNC network drive.  I think that is contributing to the problem, but still, I believe this should work.  Does anyone have any idea how I can get this straightened out?

Comment: can you re-write the queries in `Macro_Prep_Liabilities` to allow them to move faster?

Comment: Does it always work when executing the macro from Access? Are you connecting to the network via a cabled connection or WiFi? Is the network drive remotely located or on-site? If your network connection is instable and you're running your database of a network drive, you're bound to run into problems like this.

Comment: Yes, it always works from Access and I'm connection through a cable (no WiFi).  I believe the network drive is remote.  That's probably the cause of the problems.  I really can't do anything about that.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: From what you describe, that it's working "from Access" just not using automation, I don't see why you should write it off as a network issue. There are various debugging steps to observe the behavior and get more detail. For instance, try setting `accApp.UserControl = True` and `accApp.Visible = True` then eliminate the SetWarnings calls and do NOT call `accApp.Quit`. That should keep the new Access instance open and let you observe it as it's running the macro. A Macro can contain code to do essentially anything but you don't reveal any of that. Does it use linked tables, call VBA code, etc?